# Django filter reversed foreignkey

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have these tables in a django app:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ...

class SubOrder1(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, blank=True, null=True)

class SubOrder2(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, blank=True, null=True)

...
```

How can I write a query on Order which results only the orders which has at least one related SubOrder1 or SubOrder2? I need something like

```
Order.objects.filter(suborder__count__ge = 1, ...)
```

I am using Django = 1.9.2 and Python = 3.4.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [isnull](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#isnull) field lookup:

```
orders_with_suborders = Order.objects.filter(
    Q(suborder1__isnull=False) | Q(suborder2__isnull=False)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, that' s what i was looking for.

Comment: This may give duplicates unless you use `distinct()`.

Answer (score 2):

[Annotate your queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) with the counts of the related models:

```
from django.db.models import Count

queryset = Order.objects.annotate(
    num_suborder1=Count('suborder1', distinct=True),
    num_suborder2=Count('suborder2', distinct=True),
)
```

See the docs about [combining multiple aggregations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations) to explain why we need `distinct=True`

Then you can use `Q` to filter objects where either of the counts is at least 1.

```
orders_with_suborders = queryset.filter(
    Q(num_suborder1__gte=1) | Q(num_suborder1=1__gte=1),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution i just found would be something like:

```
Order.objects.filter(suborder1__id__gt = -1)
```

and i could use the same for SubOrder2. This is a solution, but not really djangonic. Is there any better solution?

Comment: Note that you may get duplicate results for each suborder. You can use `distinct()` to avoid this.

Answer (score -1):

You can get to the `SubOrder1` from `Order`.

```
order = Order.objects.get(pk=pk)
suborders1 = order.suborder1_set.all()
```

Then you can iterate through the suborders:

```
for suborder in suborders1:
  print (suborder)
```

Hope it help you